# Text filed and dropdown validation without submit in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am validating a textfield and dropdown. Both can be empty or both must be filled. I looked into below sample, but it validates only on button click. I need to validate once the user moves to some another field in the form without filling the text filed and after selecting the dropdown, similar to onblur event. I could not find any samples to my issue. Any pointers to my question ?

Comment: Strictly,  Come with your code. Explanation is next

Comment: You have two "depending on each other" form objects, how come you want to validate on blur? The user cannot fill in them simultaneously. A better aproach will be to validate the form on Submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the trick with `ng-touched`. It is applied when the element has lost focus.

These class can be combined with Angular validation and a ng-class

```
ng-class="{'has-error':yourModelObject.$invalid && yourModelObject.$touched}"
```

To make something like:

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error':yourModelObject.$invalid && yourModelObject.$touched}"">
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourModelObject" required>
<div>
```